# Windows does not detect my PDA anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I have been developing an application for my pda for several days but today something weird hit me. I worked for a few hours, i closed my laptop and when i opened it again Windows Mobile Device Center couldn't find my mobile device. I am trying for few hours and i really don't know what to reinstall to get it back. This is getting really ridiculous, please give me a hint.
I am using windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try system restore to the last restore point if its available.

Also to se if its USB issues try to use this utility [USBVIEW](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to uninstall it.

Comment: I reinstalled all(3) usb drivers and also reinstalled windows mobile device center(WMDC) but with no results. The only time windows detects something is when i install WMDC and it sais that the device cannot be installed.

Comment: Wonderfull...not! How about the system restore using an old restore point prior to this issue? Remember that restore point doesn't touch the files you created, only touches the system files/regedit/programs